# Shortest Path Dijkstra Java

Tags: java, matrix, graph-theory, dijkstra

I am trying to print the shortest path for a specific adjacency matrix using dijktra's algorithm. My dijkstra algorithm works fine, I am getting the correct distances. However when printing out the path I am getting an incorrect path. Here is my code for printing the path:

My first class is my driver that takes in an adjacency matrix. The matrix contains the size at the top of the file, the actual matrix in the middle, and the source vertex at the end of the file. That all works fine for calculating the shortest distance. The following is my full code.

```
public void findPath(int size, int s) {

    // print the path and the distance of each vertex

    int j;
    // iterate to find the distances
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print("[" + distance[i] + "] ");

        if (i != 0) {

            System.out.print(s);
            j = i;
            do {

                j = path[j];
                System.out.print(" <- " + j);

            } while (j != startVertex);

        }

        System.out.println();

    }

}
}
```

Comment: How certain are you that `My dijkstra algorithm works fine, I am getting the correct distances` since you cannot display them correctly?

Comment: @Eypros  Because the distance is displaying properly. For example, my distance from 2 - 1is [5] so that is displaying properly. The path itself, going from 2 to 1 is not displaying properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following problems in your `findPath` method:

1. You are skipping output for no reason with the `if (i != 0)` line.
2. Your data is in the form of 0-based indices, and your desired output is 1-based, and you aren't converting between them.
3. You are outputting data in the opposite order of what you want, printing the path's starting point first when your expected output puts the starting point last.
4. By following one step in the path before printing anything, you are skipping the path's first step.
5. By using a `do` loop instead of `while`, you are printing spurious "move by standing still" path steps for short paths.

I haven't examined your dijkstra logic much, but these errors in combination would transform path data that matches your expected output into the observed output, so I think you're correct that the dijkstra algorithm is working properly.

Fixing most of these should be trivial, but fixing error #3 will require a minor algorithmic change - trace and reverse the path before outputting any of it.

For greater clarity, here's your original code with all the fix points marked:

```
public void findPath(int size, int s) {

    // print the path and the distance of each vertex

    int j;
    // iterate to find the distances
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print("[" + distance[i] + "] ");

        // FIX #1: Remove this if statement
        if (i != 0) {

            System.out.print(s);
            j = i;
            // FIX #5: Use while instead of do
            do {

                // FIX #4: swap the order of these two lines
                j = path[j];
                // FIX #2: print j+1, not j
                // FIX #3: Instead of print, push onto a stack
                System.out.print(" <- " + j);

            } while (j != startVertex);

            // FIX #3: Put your pop-and-print loop here. It should not
            // involve i, and should end when the stack is empty, not
            // any other condition.
        }

        System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got rid of my if (i != 0) line and changed my do loop into a while loop and that seems to make some progress. However I am trying to implement reversing the order of my path array now. Would reversing the array's contents do the justice for this purpose?

Comment: @ExecutionStyle No, that would just jumble things randomly. You are traversing the array in effectively random order, you need to trace that order, store it in a separate list, and then use the separate list to make your output.

Comment: Would I be able to go about this by creating a stack? Trace each previous vertex and push them in reverse order? I am trying to write out the logic on paper and then implement it in Java, but I am having a hard time picturing the actual tracing of the path array.

Comment: @ExecutionStyle Yes, a stack would be perfect for this. Push each vertex onto a stack instead of printing, and then in a separate loop pop and print until the stack is empty.

Comment: hmm..I have implemented a stack and it seems to be giving me the same output. I figured that should work since stack is last in first out, which would give me the reverse order needed..

Comment: // print the path and the distance of each vertex
  int j;
  // iterate to find the distances
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   j = i;
   while (j != startVertex) {

    j = path[j];
    pathfinder.push(j);
    // System.out.print(" - " + j);
   }
  }
  // seperate loop to pop and print the vertices
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   System.out.print("[" + distance[i] + "] ");
   System.out.print(s);
   j = i;
   while (j != startVertex) {

    j = pathfinder.pop();
    System.out.print(" - " + j);
   }
   System.out.println();

Comment: @ExecutionStyle Why did you make a second for loop? There's no need for it, and it just confuses the issue. You also didn't fix issues 2 and 4. See my edit for a bit more clarity.

Comment: Ok I took out the other for loop and fixed the recommended fixes above. Now I am getting output: [5] 2 and nothing else after that. I have added the modified code to your edit, is there something I am doing completely wrong up there?

Comment: @ExecutionStyle I think editing your question rather than my answer would be the better way to show your progress. In any case, you still missed fix #4, and in the print loop you need to use what `pop()` returns. Edit: Whoops, just noticed the whopper mistake

Comment: @ExecutionStyle For fix #4, I did not mean change `j = path[j]` to `path[j] = j`. I meant put the `j = path[j]` line, unaltered, after the `pathfinder.push(j)` line.

Comment: By nothing else I mean that nothing comes after [5] 2. Either in that first line or anywhere. The code is looping infinitely. When stepping through in the debugger I am looking at the stack and only 0's are pushed onto the stack infinitely. Edit: The line swap definitely fixed the infinite looping. Now it is just printing different values. Everything that is not the source vertex is being printed as 11.

Comment: @ExecutionStyle Everything is coming out as 11 because a) `j` is always equal to `startVertex` at that point, and b) the `+` operators are evaluated left to right - it appends `j` (which is 1) to the string, and then appends 1 to the string. Put parentheses around the addition so it will add before appending, and print `pathfinder.pop() + 1`, not `j + 1`.

Comment: that did the trick! Thank you for all of your explanations sir.